# Why my h2 database is not finding doctor and patient ids?

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf, h2

So, i've been creating a hospital system on java using thymeleaf, spring and h2 database. I got a function which should insert a new appointment with previously made doctors and patients, but my h2 database is not showing their ids, it just says null.

Here's the function in controller

```
    @PostMapping(value="/insertNewAppointment")
    public String insertNewAppointmentPost(Appointment appointment, Patient patient, Doctor doctor)
    {

        System.out.println(patient.getName());
        System.out.println(patient.getSurname());
        System.out.println(doctor.getName());
        System.out.println(doctor.getSurname());
        System.out.println();
        Patient newPatient = patientRepo.findByNameAndSurname (patient.getName(), patient.getSurname());
        System.out.println(patient);


        Doctor newDoctor = doctorRepo.findByNameAndSurname (doctor.getName(), doctor.getSurname());
        System.out.println(doctor);

        Appointment newAppointment = new Appointment(appointment.getTime(), newPatient, newDoctor);
        appointmentRepo.save(newAppointment);







        return "redirect:/showAllDoctors";
    }
```

And here are the classes

Patient

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "PatientTable")
public class Patient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_P")
    private int id_P;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "isHospitalised")
    private boolean isHospitalised;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "patient")
    private Collection<Appointment> allAppointmentsP;




    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "u_ID")
    private User user;
```

Doctor

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "DoctorTable")
public class Doctor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_D")
    private int id_D;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "officeNumber")
    private short officeNum;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "id_U")
    private User user;


    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "doctor")
    private Collection<Appointment> allAppointmentsD;
```

Appointment

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "AppointmentTable")
public class Appointment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "app_ID")
    private int app_ID;

    @Column(name = "time")
    private String time;

    @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "id_P")
    private Patient patient;

    @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "id_D")
    private Doctor doctor;
```

Doctor and Patient repos got this line only

`Doctor findByNameAndSurname(String name, String surname);`

and the insertnewappointment html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <body>
    <h2>Add a new appointment</h2>

        <form action="#" th:action = "@{/insertNewAppointment}" th:object = "${appointment}"  method = "post">

            Time (DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm)
            <input type = "text" th:field = "*{time}" /> <br>

            Patient Name
            <input type = "text" th:field = "*{patient.name}" /> <br>
            Patient Surname
            <input type = "text" th:field = "*{patient.surname}" /> <br>
            Doctor Name
            <input type = "text" th:field = "*{doctor.name}" /> <br>
            Doctor Surname
            <input type = "text" th:field = "*{doctor.surname}" /> <br>


            <input type = "submit" value = "Add new appointment" />


        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

````
I posted the lines i got in repos. This is the function that loads the data in, with this everything is alright, the id show up as they should on the h2 database. ```@GetMapping(value="/testingData")
    public String testing()
    {
        User u1 = new User("Janis", "123");
        User u2 = new User("Juris", "321");
        User u3 = new User("Jana", "jana123");
        User u4 = new User("Peteris", "peteris123");
        User u5 = new User("Matiss", "134");
        User u6 = new User("Jana", "JanA");

        userRepo.save(u1);
        userRepo.save(u2);
        userRepo.save(u3);
        userRepo.save(u4);
        userRepo.save(u5);
        userRepo.save(u6);

        Patient p1 = new Patient("Janis", "Berzins", true, u1);
        Patient p2 = new Patient("Juris", "Kalnins", true, u2);
        Patient p3 = new Patient("Jana", "Jauka", true, u3);

        patientRepo.save(p1);
        patientRepo.save(p2);
        patientRepo.save(p3);

        Doctor d1 = new Doctor("Peteris", "Krumins", (short) 101, u4);
        Doctor d2 = new Doctor("Matiss", "Ozolins", (short) 102, u5);
        Doctor d3 = new Doctor("Liene", "Karklina", (short)103, u6);

        doctorRepo.save(d1);
        doctorRepo.save(d2);
        doctorRepo.save(d3);

        Appointment a1 = new Appointment("26-JUN-2019 13:30", p2, d1);
        Appointment a2 = new Appointment("30-JUN-2019 10:15", p1, d3);
        Appointment a3 = new Appointment("02-JUL-2019 15:45", p3, d2);

        appointmentRepo.save(a1);
        appointmentRepo.save(a2);
        appointmentRepo.save(a3);


        return "ok";```
````

Comment: can you please supply the results and the queries you do?
Also maybe the Repo would help.

Comment: I posted the lines i got in repos. This is the function that loads the data in, with this everything is alright, the id show up as they should on the h2 database. I added the loading data function in the first post

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `id`'s type to `long` and `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, but it didn't help. Still getting this - ```Patient [p_ID=0, name=null, surname=null, isHospitalised=false, allAppointmentsP=null, user=null]
Doctor [id_D=0, name=null, surname=null, officeNum=0, user=null, allAppointmentsD=null]``` and a screenshot of h2.database - https://prnt.sc/s49u1h

Comment: Silly question but have you added getters and setters in your bean class as I don't see it in your code snapshot ?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse, i just didn't include them because then the code would be just too long.

Answer (score 0):

By default the primary key is a sequential 64 bit number (long) so add Long

Long is better than long, as is more correct to check whether an entity has persistent identity by checking against the null value (in MySQL you can have an ID of value 0). Also some libraries like Spring base on an ID of type Long (by default) in their logic

Comment: Still gives me null, maybe i should show more code for better understanding?

Comment: try to use @RequestBody annotaiton
public String insertNewAppointmentPost(RequestBody Appointment appointment, RequestBody Patient patient, RequestBody Doctor doctor)
    {

Comment: @Ramsey please show us your findBy function and repository that extends JpaRepository i assume

Comment: ```public interface DoctorRepo extends CrudRepository<Doctor, Integer>{

 Doctor findByNameAndSurname(String name, String surname);

}```   The patient one is the same.

Comment: change Integer to Long @Ramsey

Comment: ```Patient [p_ID=null, name=null, surname=null, isHospitalised=false, allAppointmentsP=null, user=null]
Doctor [id_D=null, name=null, surname=null, officeNum=0, user=null, allAppointmentsD=null]``` Still the same, it seems it just doesnt find the patient and doctor that i previously added.

Comment: @Ramsey You should first check if you are able to pull relevant entities from the H2 db, once the results is positive you can move further trying to understand where is the mistake made. What i would is to removing all Cascade annotations and changing int to Long everywhere

Comment: @Ramsey use already existing function findById and throw and id of arrived object, put a break point and check if the patient and doctor is actually found

Comment: It doesn't seem to find them, if i did it correctly.

Comment: lets continue in chat ?  @Ramsey

Comment: Sorry for late response, yes, lets continue in chat, still got the same issue. @letMeThink